# I can't add documents to a new collection (MERN stack)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mern

In a mern stack project, I created a second model and imported it to my index.js but when trying to add a document to this collection I couldn't. I don't know where is the problem,
I already created a model and everything was fine when I was making its routes. but for the new model, it doesn't work fine. I don't know if I'm missing something
Here is my code :

// users.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const {Schema} = mongoose;

const usersSchema = new Schema(
    {
        firstName:{type: String, required: true},
        lasttName:{type: String, required: true},
        dateBirth:{type: Date, required: true},
        gender:{type: String, required: true},
        email:{type: String, required: true},
        password:{type: String, unique: true, required: true},
        role:{type: String, default: "User", required: true},
        school:{type: String, required: true},
        subject:{type: String, required: true}
    }, 
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
)

const userModel = mongoose.models.userModel || mongoose.model("users", usersSchema);

module.exports = userModel;
```

// index.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const connectDB = require("./connectDB");
const cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");
const compression = require('compression');
const classModel = require("./models/classes");
const userModel = require("./models/users");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");


const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

connectDB();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded( {extended: true} ));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(compression());
app.use(cookieParser());

//--- classModel Routes ---//
Here there are some routes

//--- userModel Routes ---//

app.post("/api/users", async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
        const newUser = {
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            gender: req.body.gender,
            dateBirth: req.body.dateBirth,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword,
            role: req.body.role,
            school: req.body.school,
            subject: req.body.subject 
        }
        await userModel.create(newUser);
        res.json("A new user has been added successfully!");
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occured while adding a user!"});
    }
});

//--- global Routes ---//

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json("Hello World!");
});

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus("404");
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on PORT: ${PORT}`);
});
```